# Django represent a many-to-many relationship as a CharField

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many field on one of my models and a ModelForm to represent it. I have it in a template but it shows up as a multiple select field. I need it to show up as a CharField so the user can put in comma-delimited values. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code in [django.contrib.admin.widgets.ForeignKeyRawIdWidget](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L126) to see how the admin's raw_id_fields are implemented and try specifying it as the `widgets=` kwarg when you define that field on your form.